# TypeScript Dynamic Objects Migration

Tags: typescript

I have legacy JS that I am porting to TS.

There are many instances where an object was created:

```
var myObj = {key0: 'data0', key1: 'data1'}
```

and then dynamically add properties to this object later on:

```
myObj.key2 = 'data2'
```

However TS complains that property 'key2' does not exist on '{

What is the correct way to fix this. I can do

```
(myObj as any).key2
```

but this obviously defeats the purpose of using TS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends, but in this case you probably want to define a type:

```
interface KeyedObj {
  key0: string,
  key1: string,
  key2?: string,
}

const myObj: KeyedObj = {key0: 'data0', key1: 'data1'};
myObj.key2 = 'data2';
```

You could also simply declare `myObj` as `any`:

```
const myObj: any = ...
myObj.key2 = 'data2'; // no type issue here
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use an index signature:

```
var myObj: {[key: string]: string} = {key0: 'data0', key1: 'data1'}

myObj.foo = "bar"; // okay
myObj["bar"] = "foo"; // okay
```

Read about index signatures [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).